# Where does Modern Warfare 3 save your profile information?

Tags: steam, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I'm wondering where Call of Duty Modern Warfare 3's saved games folder sits, especially when you use steam to install and play the game.

After "tricking" Steam to installing it from the disk, rather than downloading it from the Internet, it never asked where I would like to install it (from what I can remember) and it doesn't put it under the usual program files (x86) folder.

I would like to find this out so that I can backup my saved games, in case something happens to them.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about installing from the disk, but my MW3 on steam saves seems to be inside the steam folder itself:

> [path to steam]\steamapps\common\call of duty modern warfare 3\[profile name]\save

Comment: Ah awesome :) thank you so much :) I found it and all the saves are there :) (sorry, im fairly new to steam, so its great when you find out new things ) :) thanks again!